# not able to store the data on the sdcard

Tags: android

In the Eclipse i am able to see the SDCard and it opens the window to upload the data to the SDCard but shows the error as below:
**-Failed to push the item(s).
-(null)**

how can i solve this any idea?

I have tryed this after restarting the Eclipse.

Comment: Try using `adb kill-server` & `adb start-server` at command prompt.

Comment: its done. i forget to mount the sdcard

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer, and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

u can  mention the sdcard size in u r emulator to open settings  terminal controller just click me open the sqlite db to open sdcard to  see the details this is help full